# Using Maatwebsite Excel 3.1 Export how to set background color for cells and font size for heading?

Tags: php, laravel-6, maatwebsite-excel

I Am using Maatwebsite Excel 3.1 for export functionality. How can we set the background color for cells and and font size for headings?.Could you please help me to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, implement `WithHeadings` and add `use RegistersEventListeners`. This will allow you to use `afterSheet` method autowired to the event:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class BomExport implements FromArray, WithEvents
{
    use RegistersEventListeners;

    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        // Add styling here
    }

    // ...
}
```

For alternative ways of placing your styling code, check the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html).

In `afterSheet` method, you can access the underlaying library and its `Worksheet` object (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet):

```
$sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();
```

Using that object, you can e.g.:

- Set font size, weight and color on the first row:

  ```
  $sheet->getStyle('1')->getFont()
      ->setSize(16)
      ->setBold(true)
      ->getColor()->setRGB('0000ff')
  ```
- Set background color on the second column:

  ```
  $sheet->getStyle('B')->getFill()
      ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
      ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
  ```
- Set border thickness on a cell:

  ```
  $sheet->getStyle('D3')->getBorders()->getAllBorders()
      ->setBorderStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK);
  ```
- Set row height:

  ```
  $sheet->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(26);
  ```

For more options, see the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#styles).

Unfortunately, styling whole rows (`$sheet->getStyle('1')`) and columns (`$sheet->getStyle('B')`) doesn't work in Excel Mobile (version 16001.12325.20032.0) I had to use cell ranges (`$sheet->getStyle('A1:Z1')` or `$sheet->getStyle('A1:A999')`)

Putting it together:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class BomExport implements FromArray, WithEvents
{
    use RegistersEventListeners;

    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        $sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();

        $sheet->getStyle('1')->getFont()->setSize(16);
        $sheet->getStyle('1')->getFill()
            ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
            ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use html and the `FromView` concern.
[documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/blade/styling.html)
Example Maatwebsite Export [FromView concern](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html):
Run artisan command: `php artisan make:export ExampleExportView`
Change `ToCollection` class that is outputted to below `ToView` class (php artisan help does not show a `ToView` option, so we have to change it ourselves).

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class ExampleExportView implements FromView
{
    private $table;
    public function __construct($table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        $tableHtml = $this->table;
        return view('exports.exampleview', compact('tableHtml'));
    }
}
```

In the `exports` directory create `exampleview.blade.php` file with laravel echo:

```
{!! $tableHtml !!}
```

From your controller build the html table and instantiate the `ExampleExportView` class passing the html table to the constructor while returning the download method of the `Excel` facade:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Exports\ExampleExportView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function downloadExcel()
    {
      $filename = "example_excel_maatwebsite_from_colour_view";
      $table = <<<TABLE
<h2>Maatwebsite Excel FromView</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style='background-color: #007bff; color: #f8f9fa;'>Heading one blue</th>
            <th style='background-color: #dc3545; color: #f8f9fa;'>Heading two red</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style='background-color: #ffb759;'>18 Yellow</td>
            <td>17 no colour</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
TABLE;
    return Excel::download(new ExampleExportView($table),
        $filename .'.xlsx');
    }
```

Register your route:

```
Route::get('download-excel-html-table', 'ExampleController@downloadExcel')
     ->name('download-excel-html-table');
```

Place the route in your index blade and it will download the excel file with five cells filled with data. 
Cell 'A1' will have a large header with word `Maatwebsite Excel FromView`.
Cell 'A2' will have value `Heading one blue` as well as a blue background with white text and 'B2' will have value `Heading two red`  as well as a red background with white text, while 'A3' will be yellow with value `18 Yellow` and 'B3' no colour with value `17 no colour`.
You can also use inline css to style html (all documented):

```
<html>
    {{ HTML::style('css/table.css') }}

    <!-- Cell styled with class -->
    <td class="cell">Cell</td>

    <!-- Cell styled with ID -->
    <td id="cell">Cell</td>
</html>
```

Of course this is a small static example.  I build large 'sheet' fillers by looping over data arrays and allocating colours to html td's.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
 $sheet->row(1, ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3']); // etc
 $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
     $row->setBackground('#CCCCCC');
 });
```

Also you can change $sheet->row() to $sheet->cell() and keep passing a row number as first argument.

```
 $sheet->cell(1, function($row) { 
     $row->setBackground('#CCCCCC'); 
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a controller

```
public function exportComplaint($request) 
{
   return Excel::download(new ComplaintExport($complaintData), 'excel.xls');
}
```

And in App\Exports

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ComplaintExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
   protected $request = null;
   public function __construct($request)
   {
      $this->request = $request;
   }
   public function array(): array
   {
      return $this->request;
   }
   public function headings(): array
   {
      return ['name','contacts']; //etc
   }
}
```

In the above code where i need to add `sheet` function?

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been posted in the question.